# How can I use ftp files as data source for Machine Learnig Azure?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, ftp, qliksense

I need to connect Machine Learning studio to data that are available in ftp (credentials): extract data file from ftp for train process + extract data file from ftp for predict process + send file results to ftp.

The only data source for file extraction (no db) I have seen is via local pc.

Thank you for any help.

Mohamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use urllib do download the file locally with Python, and then load it.
Soemthing like this:

```
import urllib 
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://username:password@server/remote_path_to_file', './local_path_to_file')
```

Comment: I write this in the window "import data" space "data source url"?